# How can I make an array of arrays of custom objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

So, I have a friendly neighborhood object constructor, like so;

```
function Clip(a, b)
{
    this.track = a
    this.slot = b
    this.path = "live_set tracks " + a + " clip_slots " + b + " clip "
    clip = new LiveAPI(this.patcher, this.path)
    this.length = clip.get("length")
}
```

What I'd like to do is

1. Add an an arbitrary number of them to an array
2. When the length of the array hits 8, add that array to a new "super"array and start a new array.

In other words, the superarray should allow me to access the objects' properties and methods by, for instance, `clip[0][0].length - clip[0][7].length`, `clip[1][0].length - clip[1][7].length`, etc.

Comment: array, superarray...why not work with objects instead?

Comment: Sounds like some sort of B-Tree setup.

Comment: @Pointy [MDN: Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy), [Harmony: Proxy proposal](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:proxies). It's only supported in Firefox 4+, and Chrome 19+ (with the experimental flags set). It's not ready for use in production though.

Comment: @james Can you clarify your question? What exactely do you need? Dynamic getters/setters, or help with engineering?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? I simplified some of the code, but the general idea seems to fit.

http://jsfiddle.net/bryandowning/pH6bU/

```
var superArr = [];

function Clip(a) {
    this.length = a;
}

/*
* num: number of clip collections to add to container
* max: number of clips per collection
* container: array to add collections to
*/
function addClips( num, max, container ){

    while(num--){

        // arr: a collection of clips
        var arr = [];

        for( var i = 0; i < max; i++ ){

            arr.push(
                // just did a random number for the length
                new Clip( Math.floor( Math.random() * 10 ) )
            );

        }

        container.push( arr );

    }

}


addClips( 5, 8, superArr );

console.log( superArr );

console.log( superArr[0][0].length );


​
```

Comment: So basically you're saying, make a global array from outside the function, refer to it in the args and then do this?

Comment: `container` is just a named parameter for the `addClips` function. There isn't actually anything called `container` outside the scope of the `addClips` function. In my example I created a global array called `superArr`. It doesn't have to be global, it just needs to be accessible from wherever you call `addclips`. `superArr` gets passed to `addClips` which makes it the `container` inside the scope of `addClips`. Make sense?